# sys.argv in a windows environment

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I'm attempting to learn python using the book 'a byte of python'. The code:

```
import sys

print('the command line arguments are:')
for i in sys.argv:
    print(i)

print('\n\nThe PYTHONPATH is', sys.path, '\n')
```

outputs:

```
the command line arguments are:
C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/helloWorld/module_using_sys.py


The PYTHONPATH is ['C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\helloWorld', 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\helloWorld', 'C:\\Python34\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

when the book said that the output should be:

```
The command line arguments are:
module_using_sys.py
we
are
arguments


The PYTHONPATH is ['/tmp/py',
# many entries here, not shown here
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

The book is written for python 2, whereas I am using python 3. My question is **why is there a difference?**

Comment: And did you actually provide those arguments on the command line?

Comment: The program output is absolutely correct, the difference in command line argument is because you did not provide it and the difference in Path is because the working folder and the lib paths are different

Comment: Output looks fine. You looped through your args and printed the sys.path. One thing to remember is that the first argument or     sys.argv[0] is always the scriptname

Comment: @Bharadwaj Okay that makes sense. I was using the run function in my IDE, so I didn't even pay attention to the command supposed to be entered into the console. Is there a way to provide these within an IDE or do I always have to use the command line to provide arguments?

Comment: If you use PyCharm then you add the arguements here `Run>>Edit Configurations` and place the args in `Script parameters`

Comment: @Bharadwaj I use PyCharm. Thanks that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the script wrong

Bring up a cmd (command line prompt) and type:

```
cd C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/helloWorld/
module_using_sys.py we are arguments
```

And you will get the correct output.